# Mounting a FileDatasets in Azure ML Services

Tags: azure, tensorflow, azure-machine-learning-service

I am facing a problem with the Dataset module in Azure Machine Learning Services. I created a FileDataset with a bunch of images to train a model in TensorFlow. I’m mounting the dataset in the target compute and then passing the mounting point to the train script as described [in the sample notebook we have on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/datasets/datasets-tutorial/train-with-datasets.ipynb).

I tried two approaches: to pass the path as an script parameter (as suggested on GitHub) and as a named input, but none of them seem to pass the mounting point correctly.  Anyone does know which is the correct way to make it work? (I can make it work with Data Sources btw)

As script parameter

```
script_params = {
    '--data-folder': dset.as_named_input('dogscats_train').as_mount('tmp/dataset'),
} 

src = TensorFlow(source_directory =  r'Tensorflow',
              framework_version = '1.13',
              entry_script = 'train.py',
              script_params=script_params,
              compute_target='amlcompute', 
              vm_size='Standard_NC6', 
              use_gpu = True, 
              pip_packages = ['matplotlib', 'pillow', 'numpy', 'azureml-sdk'])
```

**Mounted path:**

/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aa-ml-aml-workspace/azureml/cats-vs-dogs-tensorflow_1570799752_014bea9f/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/cats-vs-dogs-tensorflow_1570799752_014bea9f/tmp/dataset

**Actual path received in the script:**

/tmp/dataset

As named input

```
src = TensorFlow(source_directory =  r'Tensorflow',
              framework_version = '1.13',
              entry_script = 'train.py',
              inputs=[dset.as_named_input('dogscats_train')],
              compute_target='amlcompute', 
              vm_size='Standard_NC6', 
              use_gpu = True, 
              pip_packages = ['matplotlib', 'pillow', 'numpy', 'azureml-sdk'])
```

**Mounted Path:**

/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aa-ml-aml-workspace/azureml/cats-vs-dogs-tensorflow_1570804147_39168dcf/mounts/workspaceblobstore

**Path retrieved by run.input_datasets['dogscats_train'].mount('tmp/dataset').mount_point:**

/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aa-ml-aml-workspace/azureml/cats-vs-dogs-tensorflow_1570804147_39168dcf/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/cats-vs-dogs-tensorflow_1570804147_39168dcf/tmp/dataset

Answer (score 4):

In both approaches, the path you passed to `as_mount` and `mount` is a relative path, that is, it didn't start with a leading `/`, this will cause the dataset to be mounted relative to the current working directory, which in your case is `/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aa-ml-aml-workspace/azureml/cats-vs-dogs-tensorflow_1570799752_014bea9f/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/cats-vs-dogs-tensorflow_1570799752_014bea9f`.

If you would like to mount to `/tmp/dataset`, you will need to do `dset.as_named_input('dogscats_train').as_mount('/tmp/dataset')`, that is, you need to explicitly add a `/` to the target path to make the path an absolute path.

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rongduan-zhu/6689daaaa115f0b4e51d4a75201475b4) to show the effect of relative path vs absolute path.

`submit.py`: Submits a TensorFlow run

`so.py`: compares the two arguments, the first argument is the relative path, the second is the absolute path.

`driver_log_partial.txt`: is a partial output of the driver log you see in the run details page.

Now in regards to the name you passed to `as_named_input`. That name is then made available as an environment variable whose value is the same as the script argument's value, which is the path where the dataset is mounted to. The name is also made available as a key to `run.input_datasets` where the value is also the path where the dataset is mounted to. In other words, there are three ways to access the mounted path, you can choose a one that best suits your code.

Comment: Hi @Rongduan. Thanks for your reply. However, using an absolute path makes the driver to lock itself when reading the folder. Have you tried reading content from the mounted path? I also tried mounting in the /mnt/azuremnt folder where the code path is also mounted and same result. Regardless of this, if we use a relative folder, isn't the expectation that the method returns the correct mounted path?

Comment: Hi @FacundoSantiago, it didn't lock for me. I didn't change job submission script but modified my `so.py`. Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rongduan-zhu/fd6023d2e2a350db6628ca7578ad0905) for my run. Can you please share your job submission script and job script?